# Not able to upload a file in selenium: There is an error in console

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am not able to upload the Target.xls File from webdriver. I have provided the right syntax. And the syntax is attached below. The program executes fine but it is not uploading the file.

error:

```
> Error in console: "uploaders[activeUploader].upload(...) is undefined
> [reported to Rollbar]"
```

code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ad-import .file-upl .btn-upload input:nth-of type(1)")).sendKeys("C:\\Eclipse\\Im\\Target.xls");
```

page:

```
<div id="ad-import" class="modal hide in" style="display: block;" data-type="ADS">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="modal-body-inner spr">
<div class="inst-screen">
<div class="temp-screen"></div>
<div class="data-screen">
<div class="radio-grp scp clearfix btn-grp weak">
<div class="upload-container file-upl" data-uploader="FILE">
<section class="file-upload spr sections active" data-type="FILE">
<div class="file-drag-container">
<div class="file-drag-area">
</section>
<section class="file-paste hide sections" data-type="TEXT">
</div>
<div class="upload-container img-upl" data-uploader="IMAGE">
<div class="txt scp">
<div class="spr img-upl-cnt">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn lfloat template" href="/ui/rest/pi/import/sampleFile?channelType=applr&importType=amns">Download Template</a>
<div class="btn btn-primary rfloat btn-upload-pub splmin" data-loading-text="Importing..." data-action="upload">Import</div>
<div class="btn rfloat" data-action="cancel">Cancel</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide html as well?

Comment: @Saifur HTML is added. As i mentioned i dont have any error when i run the code.. When i click on Upload it is giving and error: please provide the file.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct html. I don't see any `input` tag on this at all which you have used in `cssSeelctor` plus I see a data-type attribute='FILE' only on `section` So not sure if your selector is right

Comment: @Saifur My csSelector is right.. the file shows when i debug. But when i click on upload then it says the eror"Please select a file" even when the file is added. And when i check in console i have above error in console